# Cant access actionresult when using method POST

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to access my login method on server side.
I do this with an ajax call but it does not work when I do it with a post.

Code:

```
$(".getToken").on("click", function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "api/Login",
        type: 'POST',
        data: { username: "myusername", password : "mypass!" },
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) {
           //logic
        },
        error: function (event, jqxhr, settings, thrownError) {
            var h;

        }
    });
})
```

Server:

```
[AllowAnonymous, HttpPost, Route("api/Login")]
public IHttpActionResult Login(string username, string password)
{ // some logic}
```

Routconfig:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Login",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Login", action = "Login", userName = UrlParameter.Optional, password = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

IT WORKS when i change from POST to GET.
Error message:

> No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI
>   'http://localhost:64251/api/Login'

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of passing the parameters as strings, create a Model that represents them and pass that up.

```
public class UserLoginModel {
    public string UserName {get;set;}
    public string Password {get;set;}
}
```

The data your javascript provides will have to match that model exactly, so it will need a UserName property and a Password property. Then you can change the signature of your Action to

```
public IHttpActionResult Login(UserLoginModel login)
```

I don't believe .net MVC routing natively parses strings from the body of a request to separate in to parameters. If you provide it with an object, it can easily deserialize your json to a specific type.

Also, you don't need to have multiple routes configured the way you do. One route with the pattern "{controller}/{action}/{id}" will work just fine.

Comment: The routes in the `RouteConfig` aren't even relevant because the OP's overriding them with the `RouteAttribute`. When `MapMvcAttributeRoutes` have been enabled before mapping the routes that is...